# HS Canvas image hover/swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

The idea of the project is to make a widget from this image, I know it's in B&W [grey scale full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeyXH.png). I have each image with the text in a separate image for example [First green section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auOQJ.png) of each of the sections (the blue outer ring is split into 5 images corresponding with the text)

I have made a canvas and set the images into separate divs so I can then add a hover effect which will allow me to change the image to the corresponding B&W image or a hover effect.

My issue is I cannot understand how to use an event such as onmouseover while in JS. Here is my code in full (I can use jQuery,bootstrap, anything).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>PI Security Widget</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <!--[JQuery]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <!--[JQuery]-->

    <!--[CSS]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <link href="css/effects.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[END CSS]-->

    <!--[Bootstrap]>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--[Bootstrap]-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>


<!--<div class="hovereffect">-->
    <!--<img class="img-responsive" src="images/b2.png" alt="">-->
    <!--<div class="overlay">-->
    <!--</div>-->
<!--</div>-->


<div id="container">
    <h1>Test chart</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


        $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
            handleMouseMove(e);
        });

    </script>
<!--</div>-->


<div id="whitering">
    <script>
        var whitering = new Image();

        whitering.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(whitering, 69, 50);
        };

        whitering.src = 'images/white.png';

    </script>
</div>


<div id="b1">
    <script>
        var b1 = new Image();

        b1.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(b1, 69, 50);
        };

        b1.src = 'images/b1.png';

    </script>
</div>

    <div id="b2">
        <script>
            var b2 = new Image();

            b2.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(b2, 69, 50);
            };

            b2.src = 'images/b2.png';

        </script>
</div>

 <div id="b3">
        <script>
            var b3 = new Image();

            b3.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(b3, 69, 50);
            };

            b3.src = 'images/b3.png';

        </script>
</div>

<div id="b4">
        <script>
            var b4 = new Image();

            b4.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(b4, 69, 50);
            };

            b4.src = 'images/bN.png';

        </script>
</div>

<div id="b5">
        <script>
            var b5 = new Image();

            b5.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(b5, 69, 50);
            };

            b5.src = 'images/bN.png';

        </script>
</div>


<div id="greentab1">
    <script>
        var g1 = new Image();

        g1.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(g1, 69, 50);
        };

        g1.src = 'images/g1.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div id="greentab2">
    <script>
        var g2 = new Image();

        g2.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(g2, 69, 50);
        };

        g2.src = 'images/g2.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div id="greentab3">
    <script>
        var g3 = new Image();

        g3.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(g3, 69, 50);
        };

        g3.src = 'images/g3.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div id="greentab4">
    <script>
        var g4 = new Image();

        g4.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(g4, 69, 50);
        };

        g4.src = 'images/g4.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div id="greentab5">
    <script>
        var g5 = new Image();

        g5.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(g5, 69, 50);
        };

        g5.src = 'images/g5.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div id="greentab6">
    <script>
        var g6 = new Image();

        g6.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(g6, 69, 50);
        };

        g6.src = 'images/g6.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div id="yellowtab1">
    <script>
        var y1 = new Image();

        y1.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(y1, 69, 50);
        };

        y1.src = 'images/y1.png';

    </script>
</div>

<div class="yellowtab2">
    <script>
        var y2 = new Image();
        y2.id="yellowtab2" ;

        y2.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(y2, 69, 50);
        };

        y2.src = 'images/y2.png';

//        function changeImage() {
//            var image = document.getElementById('yellowtab2');
//            if (image.src.match("y2")) {
//                image.src = "images/y2.png";
//            } else {
//                image.src = "images/y2BW.png";
//            }
//        }
//
//        y2.onload = function() {
//            context.onmouseover(this.src = 'images/y2.png');
//        };
//
//        y2.onload = function() {
//            context.onmouseout(this.src = 'images/y2BW.png');
//        };
//


//        $(document).ready(function(){
//            $(".y2").hover(function() {
//                $(this).attr("src","images/y2BW.png");
//            }, function() {
//                $(this).attr("src","images/y2.png");
//            });
//        });

    </script>
</div>



</div>




<div id="footer">
    <h1>sadasds </h1>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I understand that when you run the code the pictures won't show up, I have a zip file with all the separate pictures but I can't seem to upload it.

Any help on how to get this working would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please do not add "urgent" to your titles - on **volunteer** sites, all questions get the same priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs just have js in them to draw an image into the one canvas so... they don't really separate your images at all. Mouseovers on canvas I believe need to test for image bounds manually too i think.

What your trying to do seems better accomplished by using svg or even image maps since all the hoverable shapes are not square. If your graphic is an svg, you should be able to manipulate and do hovers on any part of it, if you go with old-school imagemaps you can just show separate hover png's absolutely positioned over the grey graphic, but will need your image map as a clear png positioned over all the other graphics.

SVG is the probably the best solution for irregular shapes. You can then just use css to change the color on parts of it.